# Implementing Compare for std::set

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I have a struct that is just two ints that I want to store in `std::set`, while also taking advantage of its sorting properties. For example

```
struct Item
{
    int order;
    int value;
};
```

So I wrote a comparator

```
struct ItemCmp
{
    bool operator()( const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.order < rhs.order || lhs.value < rhs.value;
    }
};
```

The intent is that `Item` should be sorted in the collection by ORDER first, and then by VALUE. If I put these `Item` in a `vector` and use `std::sort`, seems to be working as expected.

I also implemented unit tests for the cases in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare

However now this test case is failing:

```
std::set<Item, ItemCmp> stuff;
stuff.insert( {1, 1} );
stuff.insert( {1, 1} );
CHECK( stuff.size() == 1 );
```

The size of the `set` is 2, violating the contract of `set`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `return lhs.order < rhs.order || lhs.value < rhs.value;` -- This does not follow a strict-weak-order.  When comparing two items, the usual paradigm is that there is one set of values that is the "major", and that is compared.  If the major items are equal, then the comparison is passed down to the sub-level 1.  If sub-level 1's items are equal, then that is passed down to sub-level 2's items, etc. etc.

Comment: `return std::tie(lhs.order, lhs.value) < std::tie(rhs.order, rhs.value);` is how I would do it.

Comment: BTW, what compiler and version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: If you have access to C++20, defaulted `operator <=>` would do the job too.

Comment: thank you for all the feedback. @RetiredNinja your solution works great, you can make it the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @retired-ninja 's comment, the answer is to ensure the comparator does proper lexicographical comparison. One shortcut to this is to leverage `std::tuple`'s operators (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp ) using this example:

```
return std::tie(lhs.order, lhs.value) < std::tie(rhs.order, rhs.value);
```